# Determine the values of $r$ for which $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\Sigma_{n=1}^{N}X_n}{\Sigma_{n=1}^{N}n^r}=1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_n,n \geq 1$, be independent random variables s.t. each $X_n$ has Poisson distribution with mean $n^r$ for some real number $r$. Determine the values of $r$ for which $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\Sigma_{n=1}^{N}X_n}{\Sigma_{n=1}^{N}n^r}=1$ a.s.

I want to apply SLLN but I need iid. After transformation, I think it suffices to prove $\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\Sigma_{n=1}^{N}(X_n - E[X_n])}{\Sigma_{n=1}^{N}E[X_n]}=0$, where $E[X_n]=n^r $. I don't know how to prove the above identity.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of convergence are you looking for? $\sum^NX_n$ is distributed as $Poi(\sum^Nn^r)$, so chebeychev gives 
$$
P(|\sum^NX_n/\sum^Nn^r-1|>\epsilon)\le(\epsilon^2\sum^Nn^r)^{-1}\to0
$$
for $\sum^Nn^r\to\infty$, i.e., $r\ge-1$. That gives you $L^2$ convergence. Conversely, if $\sum^Nn^r\to c<\infty$, Slutsky's theorem implies $\sum^NX_n/\sum^Nn^r\leadsto Poi(c)/c\neq 1.$ Another approach might be to apply a triangular array CLT to the transformed version you put in your question.

Comment: sorry, here should be almost surely.